Vaadin Upload with Selenium
Vaadin uses a POST request to a generated URL to upload a file within the Vaadin Upload component.

In Selenium all online tutorials do the file upload on an input element, which is not generated by Vaadin.
Also tried to do a POST Request to the endpoint which was not working.
Any ideas how a Upload can be done with Selenium (Java)?
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("vaadin-upload"));
String target = element.getAttribute("target");

Here I get the generated URL. POST request did not work

TestBench has an UploadElement that implements the upload for Selenium tests. But I assume that you don't have a Vaadin subscription.

yeah right, we use the public version of Vaadin

Then there is no easy way. You'll have to check how the Upload component is implemented and use some JavaScript to trigger the upload.

Yes I try now to use the JavaScript method:
But it seems the file is then broken
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor executor) {
executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName("vaadin-upload")[0].uploadFiles(new File(" + byteArrayForJS + ", "myfile.png"));");
}
